# Concentric cylinder cell constant

Tags: electricity, dielectric, batteries, electrochemistry

For a concentric cylinder cell (with liquid dielectric), mathematically the equation for the cell constant will always yield a lower value than for the parallel plate case for the same volume of fluid. I understand this from a mathematical perspective, however, I don't understand why this is the case from a physics perspective and was wondering if anyone would help in this regard. Why does a concentric cylinder allow for larger resistivity measurements with the same dielectric volume than a parallel plate cell?

Comment: This duplicates this question over in electrical engineering:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/441167/concentric-cylinder-cell-constant

Comment: My first reaction is that you must be making some unspoken assumption about the shapes of both the parallel plate case and the cylinder case.  Surely it matters whether you are talking about two large, closely spaced plates or two tiny distant plates separated by the same volume of dielectric?  I think we need more details to get you the answers you are looking for.